# Oracle APEX Social Sign In redirecting to https://...:80 after authentication

Tags: redirect, oauth-2.0, oracle-apex

We used the following tutorial to set up an Oracle APEX Application with an Azure based social sign in:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/azure-ad-authentication-for-oracle-apex-applications

It works somehow, but the redirect url provided by apex seems to result in the user getting redirected to https://our-domain/:80/ords/apex_authentication.callback?...
The browser then displays an error message. If the user removes ":80" from the url, and does not change anything else, he will get redirected to the APEX application and everything works.

Our machine, hosted by Azure has the following uname -a:

```
Linux servername 5.15.0-1020-azure #25~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 1 19:20:56 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

We are using docker for the deployment with the following two containers:

```
container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:21.3.0.0
container-registry.oracle.com/database/ords:22.2.0
```

The APEX version is 22.1.

We have not changed anything to the base configurations of Tomcat, ORDS or APEX.
SSL/TLS is handled by a nginx reverse proxy that redirects to our APEX application.

This is the chain of URLs from the browser debugging tools:
[image: URL chain]

`apex_authentication.get_callback_url` has the :80 in it, but we found no way to change it:

[image]

We will provide all further information if it helps and are very thankful for all help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it redirects to https://yourdomain.com:80, it looks like the server expects the redirect URL to use HTTP (hence the port 80), while your server uses HTTPS (which is port 443).

Your probably going to need to listen on HTTP (http://yourdomain.com:80) and change the redirect configuration to use HTTP aswell.
If the above is not an option you can try redirecting https://yourdomain.com:80 to https://yourdomain.com.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you know how to set the ORDS service for AAD to https? Since redirecting https traffic incoming on Port 80 to Port 443 does not seem to be possible on our nginx reverse proxy, because the proxy isn’t able to listen for the https Protocol on Port 80.

Answer (score 0):

When using this ORDS container (that runs with jetty) behind a reverse proxy, you need to explicitly allow certain http headers. To do so add the following two entries to your settings.xml.

```
<entry key="security.externalSessionTrustedOrigins">https://example.com</entry>
<entry key="security.httpsHeaderCheck">X-Forwarded-Proto: https</entry>
```

The settings file should be mapped as a volume in your container configuration and be located at /etc/ords/config/global/settings.xml inside the ORDS container.

Your nginx reverse proxy should be configured like this:

```
server {

...

error_page 497 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;

    location /i {
      proxy_pass http://<INTERNAL-SERVER-IP>:8181;
      proxy_set_header Origin ""; 
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location /ords {
      proxy_pass http://<INTERNAL-SERVER-IP>:8181;
      proxy_set_header Origin "";
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://<INTERNAL-SERVER-IP>:8181;
      proxy_set_header Origin "";
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

See:

- https://blog.cloudnueva.com/running-ords-standalone-mode
- https://www.oracle-and-apex.com/the-oracle-apex-reverse-proxy-guide-using-nginx/
- https://www.oracle-and-apex.com/tomcat-with-ords-running-apex-behind-a-reverse-proxy/